# Cannot find emacs 24.4 for windows

Tags: emacs

I thought that I would upgrade my emacs installation to 24.4 - but when I look in the 'windows' directory on the ftp servers (I have tried several mirrors), there is no zip file for a compiled emacs-24.4 release. The only files in the windows directory stop at 24.3.

Have I missed some fundamental point? Does 24.4 not work on windows? Is this supposed to be downloaded from somewhere else?

Many thanks, Richard.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try superuser.com or the beta emacs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit CPU; http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/

Comment: Barmar - noted, thanks.

Comment: Kokkie - Sadly no - but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the best page for information about windows builds of emacs on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWThirtyTwo), there are various folks that provide Windows build.

I've just checked each of them and determined that currently only one has a 32bit emacs24.4 build available for Windows.  It's [the emacs-bin project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacs-bin/files/snapshots/).

At this time, the one you probably want happens to be the one named `emacs-trunk-20141020T195941-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.7z`.  It is ten days old.

If you (or others) are also interested in an up-to-date 64bit build for windows, then there is another project from the list that is currently active: [Emacs-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/files/).  The most recent build on this one is nine days old at this time.

Comment: The 32bit (cited above) will require hunting down the applicable *.dll files to use Ghostscript (see `dynamic-library-alist` for a current list of the files needed); whereas the 64-bit (cited above) has them included.